# Java Generics in use case VS standard type with Enum

Tags: java, domain-driven-design

In a Java Spring Boot DDD project we have several APIs exposed.

Now for only one of these APIs we need that the "Token" entity contains one more attribute: "Locales".

In use cases that use "Token" without "Locales" I would not want the getter of that new attribute to be accessible.
For this I am considering two options:

- Add "Locales" to the "Token" entity and also another "Type" attribute (an Enum)
  that, depending on whether it is of one type or another, when
  accessing the "Locales" getter, returns the elements or an
  Optional.Empty (or an exception). This way only the use cases that are
  for the "LocalizedToken" will get the "Locales", but in my
  opinion the interface is less clear and more errors could happen when
  using attributes that are not really used in all APIs.
- Extend "Token" with a "LocalizedToken" entity and make use cases that use each
  exposed API only have access to the type it needs. For example, with
  generics, create use case: `CreateTokens<T extends Token>`. This
  option looks cleaner but requires a lot more modifications, as these
  generics are spread throughout the domain, repositories, etc.

In your opinion, which is the best approach? Or any other suggestion?

Thanks!

Comment: From the ddd perspective I would go with the 2nd option to have clearly visualised the models - one the `Token`, and the second `LocalizedToken` because as you already mentioned, it is a different conception

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't recommend using an Enum for this. In general when using Enums you're tempted to switch over the Enum type to do some action or return a response. If you later decide another type of `Token` is an option, you need to update all the existing code. This violates the Open-Closed principle.